# How to have a one line setter for the variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to do the following:

Assuming I have 3 variables:

- `var a1;`
- `var a2;`
- `var x;`

I want to be able to set "x":

- to be equal to `a1` if it is not `null`
- to be equal to `a2` if `a1` is not `null`
- to be equal to `a1` if `a2` both a1 and a2 are defined
- to be equal to null if `a1` and `a2` are both `null`

Is there one line of javascript I can do this with?

Currently I do:

```
var x;

if (a2) {
 x = a2;
}

if (a1) {
 x = a1;
}
```

Comment: `var x; x = a1 ? a1 : (a2 ? a2: null)`

Comment: Sure, you can do it in one line, but why one line? write it so that it is easily readable, then use a minifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you only care about whether the value is falsy instead of identical to `null`, use `||`:

```
var x = a1 || a2 || null;
```

The "and" and "or" operators short-circuit in any C-influenced language. Combined with Javascript's notion of truthiness, this is a powerful feature. Use it.

Comment: This may work for most scenarios, but won't work if `a1` or `a2` are falsy (e.g. `false` or `''`).

Comment: a1 or a2 are either null or objects, so no need to consider false or ''

Comment: @BhojendraNepal how? I don't see how I can randomly insert an `&&` into this expression and get something meaningful.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal it doesn't, try running it.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal if a1 and a2 are truthy, that returns `null`. In fact it always returns something falsy.

Comment: @djechlin, sorry I didn't noticed that OP has changed the statement, your code fulfills the requirement now...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal okay. still only fair to say that your code alway returns `null` or something else falsy, so there's not really any problem it might have been solving.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ternary expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). This will allow you to pass a condition instead of defaulting to `undefined`/`null` checks. This is a short-circuiting condition.

> Just like C# and Java, the expression will only be evaluated ***if, and only if***, the expression is the matching one for the condition given; the other expression will not be evaluated.<sup>[[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript)</sup>

```
var x = a1 != null ? a1 : a2 != null ? a2 : null;
```

Although the usage of [`?` and `:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript) looks like the Elvis operator (`?:`), in JavaScript you use [`||` (OR logical operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_(.7C.7C)) to perform [`null` coalescing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#JavaScript) for default values.

```
var x = a1 || a2 || null;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `?` operator

```
var x; x = a1 ? a1 : (a2 ? a2: null)
```